# Create a snowflake table from pyspark using SQLContext

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a snowflake table from my pyspark code as below:

```
import pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("create or replace table NEW_TABLE (id integer, desc varchar)")
```

I am getting this error
[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried without full path (DB.SHEMA.TABLE) and you got same error? The screenshot shows you're using a full path.

Comment: I tried providing db.schema.table_name

Comment: I understand, but without full path (just table name) you are getting the same error?

Comment: I need to provide where to create the table since I am running this from AWS glue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will create **Hive table** not Snowflake table. You'd have to write by dataframe like this

```py
sfOptions = {
    'sfUrl': '...',
    'sfUser': '...',
    'sfPassword': '...',
    ...
}

(df
    .write
    .format('snowflake')
    .mode(mode)
    .options(**sfOptions)
    .save()
)
```

OR, if you really want to trigger a single Snowflake query from Spark, you can use Snowflake `runQuery` API

```py
query = "create or replace table NEW_TABLE (id integer, desc varchar)"
spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery(sfOptions, query)
```

Comment: Thanks pltc, the last part helped where i was struggling to create stage, external tables, etc in Snowflake, from my glue job, and this helped me create them.